# Why does $rank(A) \ge \dfrac{{{{(trA)}^2}}}{{(tr{A^2})}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ and Hermitian.Why does $rank(A) \ge \dfrac{{{{(trA)}^2}}}{{(tr{A^2})}}$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: It is false for $A=0$.